# Firefox Picture Element Parent Width Too Large

Tags: html, css, firefox

The parent element of a responsive picture element does not get the correct width in Firefox (OS-X).

Is there any workaround for this bug?

```css
.picture-wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.next-element {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-wrapper">
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 1000px)"
      srcset="
        //placehold.it/1200x600 1200w"
      sizes="800px" />
   <img class="image mix-image_buffer"   
      sizes="
        (min-width: 400px) 100vw,
        calc(100vw - 50px)"
      srcset="
        //placehold.it/200x200 200w,
        //placehold.it/250x250 250w,
        //placehold.it/300x300 300w,
        //placehold.it/480x480 480w,
        //placehold.it/600x600 600w,
        //placehold.it/960x960 960w"
     src="//placehold.it/200x200" />
</picture>
</div>
<div class="next-element">Caption</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZVeYw

Result:

**Firefox**

White space between picture element and next element

[image: Firefox]

**Chrome / IE**

Works as expected (no whitespace)

[image: Chrome / IE]

Comment: is `img {width:100%}` solves it ?  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VaoNaV

Comment: Does img { display: block;} help?

Comment: @GCyrillus: It looks like that `max-width:75%;` is doing some heavy lifting, there.

Comment: @ItoPizarro remove it and see caption falling :) sometimes

Comment: @GCyrillus `img {width:100%}` scales it up and fills the white space with a to large image

Comment: FYI the `<picture>` element is experimental and shouldn't be used in production yet. There are still a [number of issues](https://github.com/ResponsiveImagesCG/picture-element/issues?q=is%3Aopen) to be worked out by the working group on how it should behave.

Answer (score 0):

The [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1149357) actually occurs for any ancestor, not just `<picture>`.

If the width is known, the bug can be worked around by setting the width via css.

```
<img class="image mix-image_buffer"   
  sizes="
    (min-width: 400px) 100vw,
    calc(100vw - 50px)"
  srcset="
    //placehold.it/200x200 200w,
    //placehold.it/250x250 250w,
    //placehold.it/300x300 300w,
    //placehold.it/480x480 480w,
    //placehold.it/600x600 600w,
    //placehold.it/960x960 960w"
  src="//placehold.it/200x200"
  style="width: 600px" />
```